# How to stop site in IIS 7.5

Tags: iis-7.5

Okay, this seems too daft to be true, but I can't see how you stop a site in IIS 7.5

Various info on the web says things like in Features View - under Manage Web Site - click Stop Web Site.

But, what I am looking at is .. Features View, but, on the right it says Manage Application (not Manage Web Site) and the only thing under that is

Browse Application,
Advanced Settings,
Help

Nowhere is the ability to stop the site presenting itself.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772137%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?

Comment: As I said in my question - I had already seen the info that says 'under Manage Web Site - click Stop Web Site'. But I am not seeing 'Manage Web Site' - I am seeing 'Manage Application' and there is no 'Stop Application' feature or facility.

Comment: So all you want is the application to stop running? what is different about your application than the website?